# Redis keyspace notifications with StackExchange.Redis For Delete operation

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack.redis

I've been searching to find out how to perform a subscription to key space notifications on Redis using ServiceStack.Redis library for removal of Key.

Checking available tests on the git-hub and other websites I've found IRedisSubscription can be used for subscribing to specific Redis key events, For set operation it is working absolutely fine but when it comes to Delete operation the action is not invoked.

Is it possible to take advantage of this Redis feature using ServiceStack.Redis and get event on delete operation too?

In the configuration file I have added this line:

```
notify-keyspace-events KEAg
```

I am using the following code.

```
var channels = new[] { "__keyevent@0__:set" , "__keyevent@0__:del" };

using (var redisConsumer = new RedisClient("localhost:6379"))
        using (var subscription = redisConsumer.CreateSubscription()) {

            subscription.OnMessage = onKeyChange;
            subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching(channels );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the surface, it looks like what you got should work.

Try setting `notify-keyspace-events` to `AKE`, the `g` is redundant, as noted in [Notifications Config](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration):

> A     Alias for g$lshztxe, so that the "AKE" string means all the
>   events.

Try using `SubscribeToChannels` instead of `SubscribeToChannelsMatching`. The latter is for pattern subscription.

You can test how many subscribers you have with the `PUBSUB NUMSUB __keyevent@0__:del` command from redis-cli.

Try testing your events are being triggered with `SUBSCRIBE __keyevent@0__:del` from redis-cli. This will help you determine if the problem is on redis-server or the app code.

Please update the question with results if you can't get it to work after trying the above.

Comment: It worked this way. I don't understand why it does not work with "g". What I understood from the documentation was that g means  is for all generic events. Then what the difference between these two?